# Reference: In general, what is the group $M_{k}(n)$ here?

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, finite-groups

Take a look at these pages on the subwiki [Groupprops](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Main_Page).

On [the page titled M16](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/M16):

> The group, sometimes denoted $M_{16}$ or $M_4(2)$, is defined as
> follows:
>
> $M_{16} = \langle a,x \mid a^8 = x^2 = e, xax^{-1} = a^5 \rangle$.
>
> Here, $e$ denotes the identity element.

[M27](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/M27):

> This group, sometimes denoted $M_{27}$ or $M_3(3)$, is defined as the
> semidirect product of the cyclic group of order nine and a cyclic
> group of order three, acting on it by nontrivial automorphisms.
>
> It is given by the presentation (with $e$ denoting the identity
> element):
>
> $\langle a,b \mid a^9 = b^3 = e, bab^{-1} = a^4 \rangle$
>
> It is part of the family of groups: semidirect product of cyclic group
> of prime-square order and cyclic group of prime order.

I would like a reference telling me the basics about this family of groups: e.g. what in general is the group $M_{k}(n)$? For what values of $n$, $k$ is it defined? P What would the name of this family of groups be (presumably something starting with an M)? Presumably $|M_{k}(n)|=n^k$.

Comment: I had never seen the notation $M_{27}$ or $M_3(3)$ before. This group is more commonly known as the extraspecial group $3_-^{1+2}$. As for the $M$, I think it stands for "modular", as I've seen that name around as well for $M_{16}$, although I'm not sure why exactly.  See https://people.maths.bris.ac.uk/~matyd/GroupNames/modular.html for example